# How to write a command line for crons job?

Tags: command-line, cron, command, jobs, email-notifications

I've been working on a little blogging system for a while now and i'm currently trying to make an email notification system to notify people when there is a new comment on the post if they are following it.

I got the notification system to work, but I can't get the crons job that will work either every hour, every 3, 6, or 12 hour (The User can choose) to work.

This is the first time I needed/used crons job and I honestly thought a command is just suppose to be something like `/home/methodjs/public_html/classified/emailNotifications.php`. But looking at some of the other commands, it seems like i'm doing that wrong.

I also got an email from `Cron Daemon` saying that there is `No such file or directory`.

Am I doing the command wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not an executable by itself. You have to do something like this:

php [your phpfile]

php is an executable file and will run with parameter of your php file.

so

```
php /home/methodjs/public_html/classified/emailNotifications.php
```

would do the job

Comment: The error message doesn't match your analysis. If it is correct after all, a simpler and more elegant fix is to put a correct shebang line in the script file (and mark it executable if it isn't already).

Comment: tripleee could be right, also refer to Cronjob sample page here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/    are you following guides in adding crobjob?